# Maximum number of threads for a CUDA kernel on Tesla M2050

Tags: cuda

I am testing what is maximum number of threads for a simple kernel. I find total number of threads cannot exceed 4096. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 100

__global__ void test(){
    printf("%d %d\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
}

int main(void){
    double *p;
    size_t size=N*sizeof(double);
    cudaMalloc(&p, size);
    test<<<64,128>>>();
   //test<<<64,128>>>();
   cudaFree(p);
   return 0;
}
```

My test environment: CUDA 4.2.9 on Tesla M2050. The code is compiled with

```
 nvcc -arch=sm_20 test.cu
```

While checking what's the output, I found some combinations are missing. Run the command

```
./a.out|wc -l
```

I always got 4096. When I check cc2.0, I can only find the maximum number of blocks for x,y,z dimensions are (1024,1024,512) and maximum number of threads per block is 1024. And the calls to the kernel (either `<<<64,128>>>` or `<<<128,64>>>`) are well in the limits. Any idea?

NB: The CUDA memory operations are there to block the code so that the output from the kernel will be shown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are abusing kernel `printf`, and using it to judge how many threads you can run is a completely nonsensical idea. The runtime has a limited buffer size for `printf` output, and you are simply overflowing it with output when you run enough threads. There is an API to query and set the `printf` buffer size, using `cudaDeviceGetLimit` and `cudaDeviceSetLimit` (thanks to Robert Crovella for the [link](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#formatted-output) to the `printf` documentation in comments).

You can find the maximum number of threads a given kernel can run by looking [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities) in the documentation.

Comment: device printf documentation is [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#formatted-output).

Comment: Thanks to talonmies and Robert.